# iOS7 : UIImageView Takes Forever to Appear

Tags: ios, multithreading, uikit, ios7

I have a `UIView` which creates and inserts views using `GCD`. It's working on `iOS7` but the `UIImageView`s takes forever to show.

Here's the sample code that I am using.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 120)];

for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(77 * i, 0, 77, 88)];
    [scrollView addSubview:view];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("image", NULL);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo@hd.png"]];
        imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 77, 88);
        [view addSubview:imageView];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
            label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Name %d", i];
            [label sizeToFit];
            label.center = CGPointMake(38.5, 20);
            [imageView addSubview:label];
        });
    });
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(view.frame.size.width * (i+1), view.frame.size.height)];
}

[self.view addSubview:scrollView];
```

By the way, I am creating many `UIView`s that's why it is threaded. Around 200 views at max.

How should I make it work? The methods inside the dispatch blocks are being called, it is just the `UIView`s are not being displayed.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't add subview in queue other than main_queue.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I also tried adding them before the thread and just set the `UIImage` of the `UIImageView` but still didn't appear.

Comment: Add UIImageView inside dispatch_get_main_queue(), and set UIImage also in this queue

Comment: have you checked the label-frame-size before adding them to superview?

Comment: Don't call any UIKit code in background queues. It isn't thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @mientus, I think you are correct :D. @Abizem, so it's okay to create the `UIImage` in the background thread then add it in the main thread? Thanks!

Comment: @mientus can post your comment as an answer? Thanks :D

Comment: @dzep Surprisingly, UIImage **is** thread safe. but adding image views as a subview is not - as it actually involves some drawing.